# Can't use success error function in $.when()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery 1.5

```
function doAjax(){
    return $.get('ajax.php');
}

function doMoreAjax(){
   return $.get('ajax.php');
}

$.when( doAjax(), doMoreAjax() ).then(function(){
     console.log( 'I fire once BOTH ajax requests have completed!' );
}).fail(function(){
   console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
}).success(function(){
    console.log( 'I fire if all requests success.' ); //It not works for me
})
```

**Question:** I can't use `success` and `error` function with `$.when` since $.when or $.ajax are same.

I can use `success` and `error` with `$.ajax` why I can't use with `$.when`

Comment: I'm confused about the question. How many donuts are you asking for?

Comment: success and error function callback not works with $.when() This is my question. I need to know why it doesnt works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got a wrong idea about it.

from the docs,

```
$.when(doAjax(), doMoreAjax())
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
// Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, 
// or myFailure if either one has an error.
```

and you might wanna read [Deffered Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I know you would get this kind of error in the console, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'success'`, simply because [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) returns a [Deffered Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).